# Does remote desktop redraw the entire screen or just the part that was changed?

Tags: remote-desktop, bandwidth

If I have a more colorful image on an RDP lock screen, will it redraw the entire screen (thus requiring slightly more bandwidth) or does it just send the parts of the screen that change (i.e. the dots where you type your password).  I've got a very pretty lock screen that some people thing might be deleterious to low bandwidth users ability to type in over-long and complicated passwords and I wanted to know if it really had any impact.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Microsoft Remote Desktop (from a Windows client to a Windows Server)

Remote Desktop should redraw only the parts that has been changed unless both the server and your client are configured to do otherwise.

By default neither are set to do a full redraw, and it requires RemoteFX which is not always available either.